# How to find resource intensive queries in Django

Tags: django, django-models, performance

How to find the execution time for various Model API Calls in Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Django debug toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [django-logging](http://code.google.com/p/django-logging/wiki/Overview) it is very helpful and will show your queries with time execution.